# Multinomial Distribution with Countably Infinite Dimension

Tags: probability

Suppose you sample from an alphabet $\{\ell_{k};k\geq 1\}$ with a corresponding probability distribution $\{p_{k};k\geq 1\}$ $n$ times (so you have an $iid$ sample of size $n$). Let the observed category frequencies be $\mathbf{Y}=\{Y_{k};k\geq 1\}$. The multinomial distribution of 
$\mathbf{Y}$ is given by 
$$ Prob\left(\{Y_{k};k\geq 1\}=\{y_{k};k\geq 1\}\right)
=\frac{n!}{\prod_{k\geq 1}y_{k}!}\prod_{k\geq 1}p_{k}^{y_{k}}.
$$ (Or is it?) How can it be shown that 
$$\sum_{ \mbox{all $\{y_{k};k \geq 1\}$}}Prob\left(\{Y_{k};k\geq 1\}=\{y_{k};k\geq 1\}\right)=1?$$

The underlying issue is whether the first expression is a legitimate expression. The legitimacy is established by the second expression, if true, of which I don't see a quick proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that by “all $\{y_k;k\ge1\}$” you mean all tuples that sum to $n$.

The countably many terms in the sum are non-negative, so we can sum them in any order. Consider the partial sum that includes all tuples $\{y_k\}$ where $y_k$ is zero for $k\gt m$. This is just the probability that all draws yield a result $\le m$, which is $\left(\sum_{k\le m}p_k\right)^n$. Since $\sum_{k\le m}p_k$ converges to $1$ for $m\to\infty$, so do these partial sums.

Comment: Yes, I meant $\sum_{k\geq 1)y_{k}=n$. A beautiful proof! Thanks.